Background geolocation Android 14 and ionic 7
I'm developing an app with Ionic 7 and Angular 17. I'm trying to use background geolocation with BackgroundGeolocation (@capacitor-community/background-geolocation) for Android 14 through the plugin watcher, but after a few minutes (2/3), it stops emitting the location.
In the AndroidManifest.xml file, I've added:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
And with the Geolocation plugin (@capacitor/geolocation), I'm requesting permissions using Geolocation.requestPermissions().then().catch();. According to the documentation, everything seems correct, but it stops emitting the location quickly.
Thanks you!!
I've tried different plugins and different code, but nothing seems to work. This is the closest I've gotten, where I managed to display the notification that it's collecting the location through the watcher.

You would get a quicker answer if you post in the github issues of the repo.
